# Objective-C, setObject in a for loop: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *timelineData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
if (timelineData) {
    NSInteger count = [timelineData count];
    for (NSInteger index = (count - 1); index >= 0; index--) {
        float score = 1000;
        [timelineData[index] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:score] forKey:@"score"];
    }
}
```

So, I have a mutableArray that I'm looping around and trying to add a new key to the `tweet` object called "score". How would I go about doing so?

At the moment, I get: `'-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that timelineData is a NSMutableArray that contains NSDictionary objects. You are sending the message `setObject:forKey:` to a non mutable NSDictionary, and that is why you are getting a "mutating method sent to immutable object.

The method : `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error` creates non mutable objects by default. If you want the objects to be mutable use the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`option:

EDIT - Forgot to add the option to the method call.

```
NSMutableArray *timelineData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments|NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

This way timelineData will be an NSMutableArray that holds NSMutableDictionary objects.

Comment: er, is the `|` a typo?

Comment: @benhowdle89 no, it is a bitwise or operator to combine your previous option with the new option.

Comment: @benhowdle89 d'oh, I forgot to add the new parameter. I'm editing the answer right now.